# TrueType WebOMints and XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, fontspec, windows

I'm trying to use the WebOMints dingbats font with XeLaTeX and fontspec, but instead of the expected output (made with the Windows font tool):

[image: expected output, from Windows font tool]

I just get tofu:

[image: tofu]

The code I'm testing with is:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{WebOMints GD}

\begin{document}
% If I do this instead of using fontspec, I just get CM ``ABCDEFG'':
%\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}
ABCDEFG
\end{document}
```

Has anyone encountered this kind of problem before?

Comment: Does there exist a TrueType WebOMints font?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `WebOMints GD` font good for usage with `fontspec`. You can use the ornament font in the classical way with all engines, though.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand{\Webo}[1]{{\usefont{U}{webo}{xl}{n}#1}}

\begin{document}

Some text in the default font

\Webo{ABCDEFG}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, XeLaTeX doesn't complain if you load the PFB font with `\newfontfamily`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\webo}{WebOMintsGD}[
  Extension=.pfb,
]
\newcommand{\Webo}[1]{{\webo#1}}

\begin{document}

Some text in the default font

\Webo{ABCDEFG}

\end{document}
```

The size is slightly different, you can use the `Scale` option to choose the best size for you.

[image]

You might also do

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{WebOMintsGD}[
  Extension=.pfb,
]

\begin{document}

ABCDEFG

\end{document}
```

but a document completely written with ornaments doesn't seem very readable.

Comment: That certainly explains why it didn't work. The reason my `\usefont` code was simply that the font wasn't installed (I'd forgotten that it's not in the downloaded TeXLive stuff), and a missing font is just a warning not an error.